# Spryker add prefix to order reference number

Tags: spryker

I am new to spryker, I want to add prefix to order reference number, but there is a prefix in it by default, I couldn't find where the prefix comes from. Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix creation is happening here :

https://github.com/spryker/spryker-core/blob/2b06c2c1e21d43098f6708b7cb0db56af57243b6/Bundles/Sales/src/Spryker/Zed/Sales/SalesConfig.php#L92

In core implementation, it is a concatenation with [predefined uniqueIdentifierSeparator](https://github.com/spryker/sales/blob/4d7b69cef875da74d786ff1a7f71e298329b0560/src/Spryker/Zed/Sales/SalesConfig.php#L62) of store name and environment prefix ,which can be set in config_default.php as

```
$config[SalesConstants::ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX] = ''
```

Extending SalesConfig in project level could be a solution.